# XSLT looking to remove attribute then rematch the element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

So I am working on an XSLT stylesheet using RenderX to produce the pdf's as the output.

At the moment I am trying to work out a way to apply some simple styles to elements when  they have a specific attribute present, and then want to match their regular template as well. I was trying to utilise xsl:copy, but I haven't manage to that to work, I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve what I wanted to do

```
<xsl:template match="node()[@ns:change='del' and not(@ns:changed='true')]" mode="#all" priority="1">
  <fo:inline text-decoration="line-through" color="#FF0000">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="ns:changed">true</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Essentially I wanted the first time the template is matched to be when it gets the strike through and is coloured red, and then it be able to match all of it's regular styling and formatting after that.

I have been trying to make a catch all solution because we have 100's of templates using different modes, so the other solution I could think of would be to check on every individual template for the attribute, but I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Currently I am running into either the issue of it becoming recursive (ie attribute not setting) or the template with priority=1 not being matched at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xsl:next-match` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match) to resume regular processing:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[@ns:change='del' and not(@ns:changed='true')]"
    mode="#all" priority="1">
  <fo:inline text-decoration="line-through" color="#FF0000">
    <xsl:next-match />
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

If wrapping an `fo:inline` around the regular formatting is not sufficient, you could set parameters on the `xsl:next-match` and then do the right thing with the parameter values in the regular template.

Comment: Perfect solution, I'd not heard of xsl:next-match before this does exactly what I need, thank you Tony